# Creating a LINQ query for a search feature

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-entities

I have a search feature in my app.  The way it works is, the user pulls up a record, the kits the search button which passes the first name, last name and date of birth from the record, to a LINQ query.  The LINQ query is then supposed to serve up possible matches.  Right now it serves up too many results.  I want the date of birth match to be exact, then the first and last name matches can be somewhat loose.  In a perfect world, the results would have:

1. Exact match to the DOB
2. Fuzzy matches to the first name
3. Close, but not strict, matches to the last name.

Example, If I am searching for James May, born 11/27/1974, I would like results such as:

Jim May 11/27/1974
Jack May 11/27/1974
James Mayford 11/27/1974

I know the best thing would be a stored procedure, but I tried that and everytime I added the stored Proc to my project, it corrupted the EDMX file, so I am stuck doing it with LINQ.

Here is what I have so far:

```
        var query = from p in _Elig_DB.PersonAttributes.ToList()
                    where   p.getDateOfBirth == DOB &&
                                    p.FirstName.Contains(FName) || p.FirstName.StartsWith(FName) &&
                                    p.LastName.Contains(LName) || p.LastName.StartsWith(LName)

                    select p;
```

This gives results like this:

```
Ileana   May         10/30/1967
Kristina May         4/23/1971
margaret Mayberry    7/26/1942
Karla    Mayorga     5/14/1986
Stan     Mayer       3/8/1952
Lori     Maynard     7/22/1965
```

So the last name is good, but the date of birth should not vary like that.  Thank you for reading.

Comment: What's your definition of "Fuzzy"-- is it .Contains()? Just so that i know what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, for the last results, what was the search query you passed in?

Comment: Micah, I passed in - James May 11/2/1984.  As noted below, Norla's suggestion fixed it so I now have an exact match for the DOB.  Actually after some testing, it is now working as I wanted.  Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just fix your parentheses.

```
    var query = from p in _Elig_DB.PersonAttributes.ToList()
                where   p.getDateOfBirth == DOB &&
                                (p.FirstName.Contains(FName) || p.FirstName.StartsWith(FName) &&
                                p.LastName.Contains(LName) || p.LastName.StartsWith(LName))

                select p;
```

Comment: NORLA, that worked, though I dont know why.  Did adding the parans make it kind of like a subquery or something?  So it matches the DOB field, then the name fields?

Comment: @teahou Google "boolean algebra."  You're performing the DOB check _and_ the name checks instead of DOB and first name _or_ starts with.

Comment: Oh wow you're right, I see it now.  Ok, well thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

sorry I cannot add comments yet but would like to add that your query is not using the where filter when getting the data from the database.

At the moment the following sql or equivalent will execute on your database.

```
select * _Elig_DB.PersonAttributes
```

All rows from the table will be newed up into entity objects. Only then the where part of you statement will be executed against the entities and disregard unwanted results.

I'm assuming this is unintentional and that you would rather want to optimise the initial query.

The reason why this is happening is because you have a 
    .ToList() 
statement on the from part of your linq statement. The tolist statement forces the query to execute immediately and build a list of objects.

If you change your statement to(without tolist):

```
var query = from p in _Elig_DB.PersonAttributes
            where   p.getDateOfBirth == DOB &&
                            (p.FirstName.Contains(FName) || p.FirstName.StartsWith(FName) &&
                            p.LastName.Contains(LName) || p.LastName.StartsWith(LName))

            select p;
```

At this point your query has not fetched any data. (Notice explicit var query type is Queryable)
Now you can execute your complete query only fetching the database rows you need.

```
var results = query.ToList();
```

Comment: HotPie - Thank you.  I have heard this a lot, because I always have the tolist at that point in my queries.  I do this because if I take it out, I get various errors.  I don't know why but I assume it is because of the way this application is set up.  I just started using LINQ so I have no other project to compare to yet.